# System of logarithmic and exponential equations $\log_{7}(x^2-x+1)=\log_{2}(y^2-1)-\log_{2}(x+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system in $\mathbb{R}$.

$$\log_{7}(x^2-x+1)=\log_{2}(y^2-1)-\log_{2}(x+1)$$

$$\log_{7}(y^2-y+1)=\log_{2}(z^2-1)-\log_{2}(y+1)$$

$$\log_{7}(z^2-z+1)=\log_{2}(x^2-1)-\log_{2}(z+1)$$

I considered the functions $f,g:[1,\infty]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=\log_{7}(x^2-x+1)+\log_{2}(x+1) $ and $g(x)=\log_{2}(x^2-1)$ both being increasing on $[1,\infty]$

And so the system is equivalent with:

$f(x)=g(y) \\ f(y)=g(z)\\f(z)=g(x)$

Suppose that $x \geq y$ then $f(x) \geq f(y) \Leftrightarrow $ $g(y) \geq g(z) \Leftrightarrow y \geq z $ then $f(y) \geq f(z) \Leftrightarrow $ $g(z) \geq g(x) \Leftrightarrow z \geq x $ this implies $x \geq y \geq z \geq x$ so $x=y=z$

Therefore the system can be rewritten as

$\log_{7}(x^2-x+1)=\log_{2}(x-1)=a$

So I have a new system

$x^2-x+1=7^a \\ x-1=2^a$

But i don't know how to prove that the only solution of this system is $x=3$ , any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $x=2^a+1$ in the first equation to get:

$$4^a+2^a+1=7^a\implies \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^a+\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)^a+\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^a=1$$

Clearly, the left hand side is decreasing, so we can have at most one solution, and that is $a=1$, which gives $x=3$.

Comment: You are assuming $x\gt1$. Note that $(x,y)=(0,\sqrt2)$ also satisfies the first equation. I think you need to make a nod to the $\log_2(x^2-1)$ term in the third equation, to justify the substitution.

Comment: @BarryCipra, Note that by the first equation, I meant the first equation of the new system (at the end of OP's question), not the original system.

Comment: @Atticus oh thanks i overlooked this method even though it was kind of obvious

Comment: @Atticus, ah, thanks for the clarification.